Ubuntu freezes when I use external monitor (NVIDIA)
Im running Ubuntu 24.04.1 on G15 5530 with GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile
When I connect an external monitor or try to boot with the monitor. Screen either freezes 3 seconds after login or on the login page. I was using nvidia-driver-550 (proprietary, tested) with the kernel 6.8.0-49-generic
I have to use NVIDIA in order to connect to the monitor. Im also using wayland if that helps.
How do I fix this?
